# How can I get post info in included .php file from single.php in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, post

This is my single.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
    <div id="content">
        <?php include('blocks/post_page.php')?>
        <?php include('blocks/fix_01.php')?>
        <?php include('blocks/fix_02.php')?>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And this is post_page.php:

```
<div id="post_page">
    <?php include('columna_01_0.php')?>
    <?php include('columna_02_0.php')?>

    <div id="single_post_block">
        <div class="b_cnt">
        <div class="logo_post"></div>
            <div class="category">
                <h2><?php the_category(); ?></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="post">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php comments_template(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that it displays just the last post info not the requested post info.

If I place `<?php if ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>` in post_page.php no post is displayed and using `the_category()`, `the_title()`, etc. in single.php works fine.

How can I get this info in the included file?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem was that one of the previous 'includes' was making a diferent query to the posts so the category query was cleared. Thank yo all and be carefull with that ;-)

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/$post

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the get_post function : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post.

```
<?php
$my_post = get_post(get_the_id());
echo $my_post->post_content;
?>
```

Hope this will help you. Sorry if I missunderstood the question.